# Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, authentication

I created simple asp.net c# web page that shows the name of the user who logged in, it works fine but the problem is when I leave the page open for a while and I refresh it or click any button on it it gives me an error and I have to go back to the login page and login again to make the error go,
 this error message:

> Incorrect syntax near '='. Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect
>   syntax near '='.

```
Source Error:

Line 22: 
Line 23:         conn.Open();
Line 24:         SqlDataReader DR1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
Line 25:         if (DR1.Read())
```

here is my code:

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from usersTable where user_id = "+ Session["userIdSession"], conn);

    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader DR1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (DR1.Read())
    {
        Label1.Text = DR1.GetValue(1).ToString();

    }
    else
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of `user_id` column? What is the type and value of `Session["userIdSession"]`? Debug your code and tell us. You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. And use `using` statement to dispose your connection, command and reader.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prooblem with your code is that if `Session["userIdSession"]` is null your query will be like this:-

```
select * from usersTable where user_id =
```

Which is obviously an invalid SQL query. Use parametrized query and check if `Session["userIdSession"]` has some value before executing.

You should first check if `Session["userIdSession"]` has some value like this:-

```
if(Session["userIdSession"] != null)
{
     //execute your code
}
```

Also, use parametrized query to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks:-

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from usersTable where user_id = @UserId", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId",SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Session["userIdSession"]);
```

Also, consider using the [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to automatically dispose expensive objects like connections.